# HTTP reuse connection condition

Tags: go, tcp, connection, keep-alive

From the official documentation https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Do it seems that the RoundTripper **may** not be able to re-use TCP connection for the next "keep-alive" request if Body is not closed and not fully read. What is this **may** about?

From what I see Close does not necessarily need to be called, when the whole Body is read. So what is the necessary requirement for connection re-use?

Code snippet (note commented out `defer resp.Body.Close()`) which creates multiple connections in a loop and from analysing it with netstat it seems the same TCP connection is used for all connections:

```
for nextPage != "" {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", nextPage, nil)
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", fmt.Sprintf("Bearer %s", *token))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // defer resp.Body.Close()
    result := []*User{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    nextPage = getNextPage(resp.Header.Get("Link"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Document doesn't say `Don't call Close() for keep-alive`. Just say `if you want to re-use connection, you MUST call Close() and fully read.`

Comment: precisely. I want to re-use, but I do not call `Close()` in the example above and it still works. So when is it really necessary to call `Close()` ?

Comment: each times when got response. The Close() is called when fully read. If you don't call Close(), it will be memory leak.

Comment: so if I have a loop where i make multiple requests to the same host with "keep-alive", I need to close the response body every time? Where can I see what kind of memory leak is occurring if I call Close only once ?

Comment: As far as I can read the docs, response body should be Close()ed for each response you got even though it's keep-alive. If Close() is called before Read(), you can confirm the Connection will be closed for each response. If the server close the connection, the response will be leak. Response body doesn't be closed automatically.

Comment: Yes, that's what docs say, however from my experiments it is enough to call Close only for the last response to free resources. The same TCP connection will be reused regardless of whether each response is closed or only  the last one, as long as the response body is fully read. But this contradicts the documentation, that's why I am asking this question

Comment: client.Do makes body reader for http.Response. It allocate memory. But it's not closed if you don't call Close().

Comment: FYI, you MUST not use defer in for loop. Because defer is evaluated when exiting the func-scope.

Comment: no, defer is evaluated at the moment defer statement is executed, the context is saved at that moment

Comment: well, you can try this. https://play.golang.org/p/vgybz4hp9J You may expect foo foo foo and finish. But not.

Comment: this is the execution order of the deferred function, not the defer statement.  The defer itself is evaluated at the moment it is declared: https://play.golang.org/p/Myf0oL3DKG

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just pointing that calling defer in loop is not good idea because it may allocate unexpected size if the nextPage is endless.

Answer (score 0):

You can only *count on* what's in the documentation. In *some* circumstances (go version, OS, architecture, response content length, etc.) it *may* reuse the connection without fully reading it, or it may not. If you want to *ensure* the connection will be reused, you *must* fully read the body and close it.

I generally write a quick helper:

```
func cleanUpRequest(req *http.Request) {
    if req != nil && req.Body != nil {
        io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, req.Body)
        req.Body.Close()
    }
}
```

This is safe to `defer` even before error checking.

Comment: yes, I deduced that **may** indicates that the rule is not a necessary requirement for having reusable connections. I was more interested on the details of when **may not** holds true

Comment: As with most behind-the-scenes implementation details, it varies and may change at any time. You can always [read the source](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=16536:16588#L480) of the `http` package for the particular version of Go you're interested in.

Comment: yes I should really dig into the code, and will make a blogpost with learnings :P